# Special Number format in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I have a table with an ID number which has a special format as follow: 2500-001
By default the number format does not accept dash(-) in the middle of number and I can not make it a Text field as I need this ID as the Primary Key.
Would you please tell me if there is anyway to achieve this in Design View?
Thank you in advance

Comment: re: "I can not make it a Text field as I need this ID as the Primary Key" - There is no reason why a Text field cannot be the Primary Key for a table as long as its values are unique and not Null.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text box input mask.

You can specify whether or not the dash is included in the data.  [See here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-HA010096452.aspx) for more information about input masks:

> #### The three parts of an input mask
>
> Input masks are made up one mandatory
> part and two optional parts, and each part is separated by a
> semicolon. The purpose of each part is as follows:
>
> The first part is mandatory. It includes the mask characters or string
> (series of characters) along with placeholders and literal data such
> as, parentheses, periods, and hyphens.
>
> The second part is optional and
> refers to the embedded mask characters and how they are stored within
> the field. If the second part is set to 0, the characters are stored
> with the data, and if it is set to 1, the characters are only
> displayed and not stored. Setting the second part to 1 can save
> database storage space.
>
> The third part of the input mask is also
> optional and indicates a single character or space that is used as a
> placeholder. By default, Access uses the underscore (_). If you want
> to use another character, enter it in the third part of your mask.